# Assign match result to a second variable and perform filter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to duplicate the results of a query to another variable, then perform some filtering on the second variable so potentially two different results return?

I'm trying to first save a path to a variable, then assign that result to a second variable, then perform a WHERE on that second variable, while returning the results from the origina query (first variable)

```
MATCH
    (a:Account {id : '3edcfba7-e95b-4d22-9793-e5f983ebde33'})
MATCH
    (target:Vertex { id : '59255ad6-0397-4b2d-9e69-6999131cea16'})
    <-[:PARENT*]-
    (a)
OPTIONAL MATCH
    p=
        (new_parent:Vertex {id : '3a63f643-f437-4415-b046-b324aa697f42'})
        <-[:PARENT*]-
        (a)
WITH
    p
    , target
    , p AS child
    WHERE
        NONE(x IN nodes(child) WHERE x = target)
RETURN
    p
    , target
    , child // this can return null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` clause to generate the `child` variable.

For example:

```
MATCH
    (target:Vertex { id : '59255ad6-0397-4b2d-9e69-6999131cea16'})
    <-[:PARENT*]-
    (a:Account {id : '3edcfba7-e95b-4d22-9793-e5f983ebde33'})
OPTIONAL MATCH
    p=
        (new_parent:Vertex {id : '3a63f643-f437-4415-b046-b324aa697f42'})
        <-[:PARENT*]-
        (a)
RETURN
    p
    , target
    , CASE WHEN NONE(x IN NODES(p) WHERE x = target) THEN p END AS child
```

The `CASE` clause will generate `NULL` if none of the `WHEN` clauses apply and there is no `ELSE` clause.